# Can't insert datetime to MySql

Tags: php, sql, date, insert

I have this weird thing when i get the date time: `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`
and try to insert it to a database, it will insert `null`. The column i insert it in is a datetime. It does not matter to what datatype i change the column it will still insert null.

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Please post the sql query and table structure, without it, there is little we can do.

Comment: Is your column a datetime column? Post more info

Comment: My guess is the column name in the query is either incorrect or you're not passing the `$date` variable in to the query correctly, i.e. typo or missing single quotes.

Comment: You need to give us enough data to answer your question. Answer the questions from the other commenters.

Comment: This is a classic "No code, no can help" question.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code, i thought it was clear to understand. I am going to try the answers i got!

Comment: You're behind your computer, we're not. The possibilities/reasons are next to endless as to why it's failing. We can't guess, we can only either provide full table creation code complete with inserts, or help with existing code. The latter being what we do most, complete code writes are usually not what people like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the column is a `datetime`, in your query instead of

```
$sql = ".... datefield = '$date' ....";
```

do

```
$sql = ".... datefield = TIMESTAMP('$date') ....";
```

Obviously the .... represents whatever your sql is at that point.